# How long and at what temp should I roast a 22lb fresh ham?

Tags: roasting, ham

I’m roasting a 22 lb fresh ham and want it to be tender. I’ve been told low and slow.

Comment: Is this a fully cooked ham?

Answer (score 1):

First wash the Ham in hot water with a rough rag. This removes the vinegar mold. Improves taste. Should feel dry to the touch. On the skin. Next glaze the Ham. I use wild honey for this. But can be done with a hard tack mix & pepper. To seal the Ham. Put in roasting pan. Place in oven at 6pm to 8 pm. Let roast at 170 to 180 F all might. 200f max. Slow cook it. At 6 to 8 AM. turn up heat to 350f. Place thermomitor at bone Bring ham at bone up to 180 f to 200 f. Remove & cool. Remove lid on roaster before turning oven up.. This is were you brown the Ham.